# Semantics of acks=1 min.insync.replicas=1 retries=10

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I'm struggling to figure out what kind of guarantees a system with this producer configuration provides

```
acks=1 
min.insync.replicas=1 
retries=10
```

The first two parameters basically give me `at-most-once` guarantees since the leader can write to local storage, reply to the producer and then die before replication to the followers.

That part is clear but the `retries` would mean that when there are network issues between the producer and the cluster the leader may write to the local disk and fail to confirm this fact to the producer. After that, the producer would retry the writing and duplicate the message.

Is my reasoning correct that this setup technically provides no specific delivery guarantee? Or is there a process on the cluster that prevents the latter from happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, the first two configuration properties provide "at most once" guarantee only.

For "at least once" guarantee, you need to change `acks` to all (or -1). This would only send an acknowledgment when all members of the ISR (leader and followers) have received the record.

Even with `acks=all`, in some cases this will still only guarantee "at most once" delivery IF there is only 1 replica in the ISR due to failures.

To ensure `acks=all` always guarantees "at least once" delivery, you need to set `min.insyc.replicas` to at least 2 (assuming you have more than 1 broker in your cluster). This would mean that at least 2 replicas must have received the record for the producer write to be considered successful. If `min.insyc.replicas` is not met, it will throw a `NotEnoughReplicas` exception.

On to the second part of your question. Yes, you can receive duplicate messages with this configuration. To prevent duplicates, you can set `enable.idempotence=true`.

However, when setting `enable.idempotence=true`, this requires `max.in.flight.requests.per.connection` to be less than or equal to 5, `acks` must be all and `retries` have to be greater than 0.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply. Do you have a link discussing this or do you speak from your own experience? All the articles I've read fail to mention this 'no guarantee' scenario for producers.

Comment: Hi, we are currently using Kafka through Confluent and versions > 7 have acks=all as the default. See doc here: https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/installation/configuration/producer-configs.html#acks

Are you using open source Kafka or another vendor, I can see if I can find a guide to send you.